# Loading data in memory in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following data stored in a file on SSD (the size of the data is 2GB). I want to load this data in-memory, such that given Number1 and Number2, I am able to retrieve the list associated with it.

```
Number1  Number2  List(in sorted order. contains maximum 1000 elements)
12       1        5585,5587,5589,5590,5594,5597,5610,5615,5618,5619       
12       2        4561,4789,4980,5001,5008,5010,5100,5150,5240,5250
12       3        3010,3223,3225,3278,3890,4890,5001

13       1        3585,3587,3589,3590,3594,3597,3610,3615,3618,3619       
13       2        14561,14789,14980,15001,15008,15010,15100,15150,15240,15250
13       3        23010,23223,23225,23278,23890,24890,25001

14       1        1585,1587,1589,1590,1594,1597,1610,1615,1618,1619       
14       2        561,789,980,1001,1008,1010,1100,1150,1240,1250
14       3        1010,1223,1225,1278,1890,1891,15001
14       4        4,89,928,3958,95859
```

I am storing this data in `std::map<unsigned,std::map<unigned,vector<unsigned>>>` as given Number1 and Number2 I want to retrieve the list associated with it.

However, it turns out that reading this data from the file and storing it in `std::map<unsigned,std::map<unigned,vector<unsigned>>>` in-memory on a 64GB server takes 5 hours. Is there some other data structure which I can use such that given Number1 and Number2 I can efficiently retrieve list associated with it. Also the data-structure should not take much time to load this data.
Also the range of Number2 (given Number1) is always from 1 to 10.

I am using: g++ (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)

Comment: Looks like you should be using a database. They're good at that.

Comment: It's quite hard to believe that it takes 5 hours, when you're not showing your I/O code. It's even harder to believe that is *has* to take 5 hours, that would imply that it's super-heavily CPU bound which it really shouldn't be.

Comment: @Mat I am writing code to create my own database. I am curious as to how databases achieve the same

Comment: Also, if `Number2` has such limited range, I'd knock them together and use `Number = 10 * Number1 + Number` as the key, for a simpler `map` structure.

Comment: It really depends on the usage patterns and concrete code, but then, i believe, this could be also a candidate for the code review part of stack exchange.

Comment: @unwind Some of the Number1 elements are like:4294967291, so adding 10 to them takes them outside their range. I dont want to increase their range to unsigned long as that will take more storage space

Comment: @StegVerner: they store the data in a format that's fast to load. And index it so that they don't have to load everything up front. Without actual usage patterns, and seeing your loading code, there's really not much we can do for you here.

Comment: @Mat I think there should be a way to maintain 2 GB of data in-memory given that the server capacity is 64GB

Comment: @wonkorealtime my usage pattern is given Number1 and Number2 I want to retrieve the List associated with it

Comment: @StegVerner: there certainly is. Again, we don't know how you're doing it now, or how you use the data. So we can't give you pertinent advice.

Comment: @Mat my usage pattern is given Number1 and Number2 I want to retrieve the List associated with it ...does that help :)

Comment: If your Number2 is always from 1 to 10, it's probably better to use a flat array of 9 instead of a map. Given the overhead on map, it probably won't increase memory usage. Also, if you don't need ordering, use an unordered_map, it will be MUCH faster.

Comment: there is - see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for a windows api

Comment: If Number1 and Number2 are in known range (e.g. always less than 20) then use:
`vector<vector<vector<unsigned>>>`

Comment: Given the numbers you're posting, you're only processing about 116.5KB data per second if it truly takes 5 hours. That is pretty putrid indeed, especially for a SSD source. I sense your heap manager wants a vacation.

Comment: @StegVerner There is no mention of what compiler you're using and whether you are timing a debug, unoptimized build (which is pointless) or an optimized build.

Comment: @AdamF Although Number1 is not in known range..but Number2 certainly is..thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am using g++ (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)

Comment: @StegVerner And the compiler optimization settings?

Comment: @WhozCraig possibly :) Any suggestion by which I can improve

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sorry how do I find that?

Comment: @StegVerner The command line options when you build your app should have a `-Ox` parameter.   http://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-o.htm  If the value of `x` it's `0`, then the discussion is pointless until you build your application using the appropriate optimizations turned on.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The optimizer option which I am using is -O3..its a big code some of which was written by another developer..so I dont know about it much

Comment: At the very minimum, since your usage requirement mandates N1 and N2 be provided, use a single-level map and a `std::pair<int,int>` key rather than a map of maps. You can jockey the key to a single `int` as unwind described if you're confident in the N1 domain not overflowing. And of course, If ordering isn't important, move to a `std::unordered_map` solution with either a `std::pair` key (you'll have ot write your own hash functor) or composite key (again, as unwind described). Personally, i'd do the latter to start. It isn't complicated and the benefits will likely be huge.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks..this suggestion sounds really nice

Comment: [See here](http://pastebin.com/M4hSJwjV) for a simple random example of the structure I referred to. It generates 1048576 entries, each with random-selected N1 and N2 key values, includes space for 0..15 for N2., and fill in a sequential of random length (750...1500). You shoud find it takes longer to tear down than the actually build. Obviously you need to rip out the random artifacts and put your own data-sourcing in, but you get the idea. Best of luck!

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks a lot. what does: (key.first << 4) | key.second; do? ..do I need to worry about overflowing unsigned if I use this?

Comment: @WhozCraig Also I am getting the error: "error: specialization of ‘template<class _Tp> struct std::hash’ in different namespace [-fpermissive]" How should I get rid of this?

Comment: 1. the left shift it to make room for the N2 composite. If your N1 domain ceiling is *below* 2^23, it shouldn't present a problem. 2. Namespace resolution as I have it there is likely not supported by your gcc (I use clang). [Use this instead](http://pastebin.com/fVw3LG6A). It should work if you have C++11 or later. You'll also likely turn things `unsigned int` as needed by you. The point of the source is simply to show alternate mapping schemes. Hope that much was clear.

Comment: @WhozCraig As my List is sorted, so do you think applying compression on individual lists will help here?

Comment: I disagree with those who say hash is much better than map. std::map is usually a blazingly fast data structure, and it has guaranteed performance 100% of the time, no re-hashes.

Answer (score 2):

Here are my suggestions:

1. Best solution really is to store the data in a database. There is not much point in implementing your own database when companies have been doing this far the past few decades. Just use one of them. You can use MySQL's MEMORY engine if you really want the data to be completely loaded in memory:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html

2. If Number1 and Number2 are integers, then maybe you can combine them to form a 64-bit long integer, and then use that is the key in your dictionary.
3. Using std::map in this case might be a bit slow, since it is internally implemented as a self-balancing binary tree, so its operations are O(log(n)). If you are OK using C++ 11 features, then you can use stl::unordered_map which is implemented as a hash, so operations are O(1).

Answer (score 2):

you may try boost::multi_index_container. Here is [an example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multi_index/example/basic.cpp)
And there are many [other examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multi_index/doc/examples.html), you can check [them](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multi_index/doc/examples.html) also. I just kown of these stuff, and hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting problem, and as usual you'll have to compromise speed and space.
Your solution is pretty bad at both, since using a map your memory will be really fragmented with so much data, and lookups will be on the logarithmic range, which is not optimal.

You could try:

```
struct Value{
  std::vector<int> _values;
}
std::unordered_map<std::uint64_t, Value> values;
```

The key of the unordered map will be Number1*100 + Number2